# Extracting covariance matrices from metagen objects

Tags: r

I was looking for a solution to extract estimates and variances of metagen objects from the meta package and use this for a forestplot and found this nice solution:

[Meta-analysis: Forest plot of summary estimates using metafor package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24326154/meta-analysis-forest-plot-of-summary-estimates-using-metafor-package)

it seems outdated though as vcov() is not able to be used with objects of class "c('metagen', 'meta)". Is there another solution to get the variances?

Comment: `metagen()` is a function from the `meta` package, not `metafor`.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. Apologies. I edited the question